# SUM() from a multi-part JOIN

Tags: sql, join, sum

```
SELECT SUM(t.OptLevel) + SUM(o.ReqLevel1) + SUM(b.nOptValue) FROM _Inventory AS i 
        LEFT JOIN _Items AS t ON t.ID64 = i.ItemID
        LEFT JOIN _RefObjCommon AS o ON o.ID = t.RefItemID
        LEFT OUTER JOIN _BindingOptionWithItem AS b ON b.nItemDBID = i.ItemID 
        WHERE i.CharID = 7843 AND i.Slot BETWEEN 0 AND 12 AND i.ItemID != 0
```

I'm having trouble with this query, I am not quite experienced with joins as I would like to be.

`t.OptLevel` is always >= 0 from `_Items` and the row is always there

`o.ReqLevel1` is always between 1 and 101 from `_RefObjCommon` and the row is always there

however, `b.nOptValue` from `_BindingOptionWithItem` is either NULL, 1, or 2 from a row that is not always there... when `b.nOptValue` = 1 or 2 is present in one of the 12 row results ( i.Slot BETWEEN 0 AND 12 ) the script runs perfectly: I get a sum total but if `b.nOptValue` returns NULL in all 12 row results the sum gets returned NULL for the whole query.

I know there is a simple solution, but I cannot find it.

Answer (score 1):

Without understanding your question, there's this cool function `COALESCE()`, which returns the first of its parameters which is not null.

```
SELECT COALESCE(SUM(t.OptLevel), 0) + COALESCE(....
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `NULL + <anyvalue>` is NULL.

You want:

```
SELECT coalesce(SUM(t.OptLevel), 0) + coalesce(SUM(o.ReqLevel1), 0) + coalesce(SUM(b.nOptValue) , 0)
. . .
```

Comment: +1 "NULL + <anyvalue> is NULL" That is certainly the root of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably start with something like this:

```
SELECT SUM(t.OptLevel) + SUM(o.ReqLevel1) + COALESCE(SUM(b.nOptValue), 0)
FROM _Inventory AS i 
    JOIN _Items AS t ON t.ID64 = i.ItemID
    JOIN _RefObjCommon AS o ON o.ID = t.RefItemID
    LEFT JOIN _BindingOptionWithItem AS b ON b.nItemDBID = i.ItemID 
WHERE i.CharID = 7843
    AND i.Slot BETWEEN 0 AND 12
    AND i.ItemID != 0
```

If a join will always have a match, then there is no need for an outer join (including left join).  Where you might not get a match, you'll need the left join and then take advantage of `COALESCE`, which returns the first non-null value it can find, which could be the constant that you provide (0 in this case).